# PyPI tarball includes files that aren't in the dist package

Tags: python, git, pypi

For some reason, every time I upload my package to PyPI, it includes a tests.py file that:

1. Isn't tracked in git
2. Isn't even in the project directory anymore
3. Isn't added to the /dist tarball after running `sdist`
4. Isn't in the tarball hosted on Github
5. Isn't in MANIFEST

Where is it picking this file up from? It was part of my package during development but I've done everything I can to remove it before publishing - and it still shows up.

Comment: point us to your package

Comment: I would, but this damn tests.py file has some sensitive information in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not figure out the issue with distutils. Switched to setuptools and everything is working correctly, no tests.py being added to the tarball.